# Why are SSDP multicast packets blocked on m0n0wall; how to unblock them?

Tags: firewall, m0n0wall

My firewall logs are being flooded with logs of packets being blocked that i don't want to be blocked:

[image]

Every 3 seconds there are 2 packets being broadcast from my machine:

- **Interface**: `LAN`
- **Source IP**: `fe80::742c:6fb9:aac3:8dc8`  *(my desktop pc)*
- **Source Port**: `56904` *(randomly assigned outgoing port)*
- **Destination IP**: `ff02::c` *(IPv6 link local multicast address)*
- **Destination Port**: 1900 *[(Simple Service Discovery Protocol)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol)*
- **Protocol**: `UDP`

These are IPv6 packets on the **LAN** interface that are being blocked. Except i **allow** *all* traffic on the LAN interface:

[image]

And just for good measure i allow **all** IPv4 traffic on my LAN interface:

[image]

Why are SSDP multicast packets on my LAN being blocked, and how do i stop blocking them?

> **Note**: The reason i am seeing them in the log is because i've asked m0n0wall to log packets blocked by the default rule:
>
> [image]
>
> i did this to confirm that no packets should be blocked, because no packets should be blocked

---

Looking at the logs in "raw" mode:

```
07:31:47.282546 rl0 @0:16 b fe80::742c:6fb9:aac3:8dc8,56904 -> ff02::c,1900 PR udp len 40 194 IN low-ttl multicast
```

Reveals nothing interesting:

- Time: `07:31:47.28546`
- Interface: `rl0` *(LAN)*
- Group/Rule: `@0:16`
- Action: `b` *(Block)*
- From address: `fe80::742c:6fb9:aac3:8dc8` *(my desktop pc)*
- From port: `56904`
- To address: `ff02::c` *(IPv6 link local multicast address)*
- To port: `1900` *(SSDP)*
- Protocol: `PR udp` *(UDP)*
- Packet length: `len 40`  *(40 bytes)*
- Other: `194 IN low-ttl multicast`

With m0n0wall's `status.php` page showing for `ipfstat -nio`:

```
ipfstat -nio
...
@16 block in log quick on rl0 all head 100
...
# Group 100
@1 pass in quick from 192.168.0.0/16 to 192.168.1.1/32 keep state group 100
@2 pass in quick from any to any keep state group 100
...
```

### See also

- [m0n0wall - understanding firewall logs](http://diyws.net/forum/index.php?topic=2382.0)

Answer (score 0):

This most likely has something to do with the fact that it is multicast traffic, try to look for related settings.